# Perl WWW::Mechanize doesn't print results when reading input data from a data file

Tags: perl, printing, mechanize

I am using Perl with [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) to retrieve the stock exchanges from Yahoo Finance, given a list of stock symbols.

The following code writes to a file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# program name: FindStockExchange.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use Storable;
use Getopt::Long;

#cmd: clear; ./FindStockExchange.pl  A AA AA.V AAA.TO -f ~/symbol_out.txt

# Find Stock Exchange for a given Stock Symbole
#  Command line options:
#    -s Symbol
#    -f Output filename

# Initialize variables:

my $urlBase   = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s = ';    # Before symbol
my $urlSuffix = '&ql = 0';                            # After symbol
my $url       = '';
my $oFile     = '';
my $symbol    = '';
my $c         = '';

# Read command line options.
GetOptions(
  'f=s' => \$oFile                                    #Output filename
) or die "Incorrect usage!\n";

# Ouptput file(s)
open(OUTSYM, ">$oFile") || die "Couldn't open file $oFile, $!";

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 0);

foreach $symbol (@ARGV) {

  $url = $urlBase . $symbol . $urlSuffix;

  $m->get($url);
  $c = $m->content;    # Places html page source text into variable

  # Text pattern: <div class="title"><h2>Electrolux AB (ELUXY)</h2> <span class="rtq_exch"><span class="rtq_dash">-</span>OTC Markets  </span></div>

  $c =~ m{rtq_dash\">-</span>(.*?)</span>}s or next;

  print OUTSYM "$symbol\t$1\n";    # Write output file
  print "$symbol\t$1\t" . "\n";    # Write to STDOUT
}

close OUTFIL;
```

The following code reads from an input file and creates an empty data file.  The input file contained the following stock symbols:

```
A
AA
AA.V
AAA.TO
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# program name: FindStockExchange2.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use Storable;
use Getopt::Long;

#cmd: clear; ./FindStockExchange2.pl -i ~/symbol_in.txt -o ~/symbol_out2.txt

# Find Stock Exchange for a given Stock Symbole
#  Command line options:
#    -i Input filename
#    -o Output filename

# Initialize variables:
my $urlBase   = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=';    # Before symbol
my $urlSuffix = '&ql=0';                            # After symbol
my $url       = '';
my $oFile     = '';
my $iFile     = '';
my $symbol    = '';
my $c         = '';

# Read command line options.
GetOptions(
  'o=s' => \$oFile,                                 #Output filename
  'i=s' => \$iFile                                  #Input filename
) or die "Incorrect usage!\n";

# File(s)
open(OUTSYM, ">$oFile") || die "Couldn't open file $oFile, $!";
open(INSYM,  "<$iFile") || die "Couldn't open file $iFile, $!";

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 0);

while (<INSYM>) {
  $symbol = chomp($_);
  $url    = $urlBase . $symbol . $urlSuffix;

  $m->get($url);
  $c = $m->content;    # Places html page source text into variable

# Text pattern: <div class="title"><h2>Electrolux AB (ELUXY)</h2> <span class="rtq_exch"><span class="rtq_dash">-</span>OTC Markets  </span></div>

  $c =~ m{rtq_dash\">-</span>(.*?)</span>}s or next;

  print OUTSYM "$symbol\t$1\n";    # Write output file
  print "$symbol\t$1\t" . "\n";    # Write to STDOUT
}

close INSYM;
close OUTSYM;
```

Why would changing from a `foreach` loop to reading an input file using a `while` loop produce different results?

`foreach` code creates a file containing the following:

```
A   NYSE  
AA  NYSE  
AA.V    TSXV  
AAA.TO  Toronto  
To-Air-Is:~ vlis
```

But a `while` loop creates an empty file.

Comment: Why have you turned off autocheck in the constructor?  You're not checking error return codes yourself, so you will now never know if the get fails.

Comment: If I look up an invalid stock symbol with autocheck on, my PERL program aborts when processing the URL for that symbol.  Turning autocheck off, prevents the $m->get($url); line from aborting the program.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but you're not checking for an error.  If you get an invalid stock symbol, your program keeps processing the page is if it got valid data.

Comment: If the stock symbol is invalid, the URL will be invalid.  Currently, the  $c =~ m{rtq_dash\">-</span>(.*?)</span>}s or next; line of code check for a valid exchange.  I will be adding a test on $m->success() to exclude processing of invalid stock symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

1) `chomp` returns the number of characters removed. But you are setting `$symbol` to the result of `chomp`. It should be something like this:

```
chomp;
$symbol = $_;
```

**Clarification in response to comment by @Vin**

You could even do this:

```
$symbol = $_;
chomp($symbol);
```

But, you should **NOT** do this:

```
$symbol = chomp($_);
```

Because `chomp($_)` *will* remove the newline from `$_` but it will return the number of characters removed.

2) If you are putting symbols on one line within the input file, then $symbol could end up being a string of more than one symbol. So you probably need to split those up or require every symbol to be on its own line

Comment: Symbols are on separate lines, had formatting issue with post.  My use of the chomp function is correct, see  [link](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/chomp_function.html).  The chomp() function removes any newline character from the end of a string.

Comment: `chomp` returns the number of characters removed while modifying the variable passed to it. Therefore if you say `$symbol = chomp($_);` you'll probably end up with `$symbol` being set to 1 in most cases. Print out the value of $symbol and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Vin See this [chomp documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) "It returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments"